# Проект Эйлера. Задача 3. Долгое время выполнения

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Написал код для задачи 3 проекта Эйлера. На небольших числах всё работает, в том числе и на 13195, которое даётся в примере, но на том, что в условии, Питон зависает на неопределённое время... Подскажите в чём проблема? Неужели настолько плохой код.. Или дело в чём-то другом?
Код следующий:

```
#The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
#What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

number = 600851475143

all_factors = (i for i in range(2, (number//2+1)) if number%i == 0)
prime_factors = (x for x in all_factors if all(x%y !=0 for y in range(2, (x//2+1))))

print(max(prime_factors))
```

Comment: Проект Эйлер не рассчитан на тех, кто только начал изучать программирование. Советую вернуться к нему позже, когда начнете изучать теорию алгоритмов.

Comment: @Chaose_in_June  Попробуем прикинуть, сколько времени занимает выполнение Вашего алгоритма. Предположим, что выполение одной интерации цикла *for x in all_factors* занимает всего 1 мкс. Количество повторений цикла равняется (грубо говоря) половине от number. Тогда общее время вычислений = 600 851 cek  / 2 = 83.5 часа = почти 4 суток.

Comment: Код неплохой. Алгоритм плохой. Смотри, нужно найти всего один множитель (самый большой),а ты зачем-то ищешь все, начиная с самого маленького. Или сразу самый большой (подсказка: range может работать на только от 2 до 1000, но и от 1000 до 2, да и шаг может быть любым). А по определению простоты числа тут примерно 100500 вопросов, посмотри там, как более оптимально это делать.

Comment: А если воспользоваться поиском, то подобные задачки тут уже решались 100500 раз, только надо их найти )

Comment: Про верхнюю границу я немного перепутал, поэтому удалил.

Comment: Чисто эстетически ещё запись `x for x in ... if...` это же явно `filter`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При рассчете простых чисел нет смысла бежать до половины числа. Есть смысл бежать до квадратного корня. Меняем

```
(number//2+1))
```

на

```
(int(math.sqrt(number))+1))
```

и все начинает очень быстро работать

Comment: math.sqrt быстрее **0.5 ?

Comment: недавно было обсуждение на эту тему. Но думаю, в этом случае это абсолютно не важно. Но побенчмаркать всегда можно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327002/which-is-faster-in-python-x-5-or-math-sqrtx - но там все не так однозначно

Comment: Только в этом случае нужно проверять на простоту как делитель, так и частное.

Comment: в прод коде - да. в рассчетных задачах на Эйлере - вряд ли